# How to fix the error 'Connection closed before full header was received' at Flutter (Dart) WebSocket

Tags: websocket, dart, flutter, socket.io, header

How to fix the error?

I have been used The Library => **web_socket_channel: ^1.0.12**

Library Link => https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/web_socket_channel#-readme-tab-?

Error Output => **WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://192.168.1.106**

My Socket Code

```
WebSocketChannel channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://192.168.1.106:80");

channel.stream.listen(
      (data) {
        print("Socket: data => " + data.toString());
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print("Socket: error => " + error.toString());
      },
      onDone: () {
        print("Socket: done");
      },
    );
```

This way I am sending a message.

```
channel.sink.add(/*data*/);
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Mert Tutsak where you fixed this issue? Facing the same and using NestJs as WS backend